# Including the new Firebase Library in Cocos2d-x projects

Tags: android, firebase, cocos2d-x, static-libraries

This is a two part question:

1. I cannot compile my cocos project via cli as the following error pops up:

```
jni/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine/firebase/analytics.h:9:26:fatal error: firebase/app.h: No such file or #include "firebase/app.h"
```

2. I can't seem to be able to include the static_libs given with the firebase_cpp_sdk into the project, i.e. where to place the architecture specific '.a' files, can I place them in the same location as my SDK header files?

Comment: I simply cannot add my Android.mk file to the question via "<pre>" anyone know how or what I am doing wrong? This is my .mk file --- LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/GameMechanics \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine/firebase \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine/firebase/admob \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine/firebase/analytics \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine/firebase/internal

Answer (score 2):

1. Fixed by adding adding a secondary LOCAL_C_INCLUDES path on up from the root firebase folder.
2. Fixed by placing the static library in the jni folder.

My final Android.mk file shows:

LOCAL_MODULE    := firebase

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := firebase/libanalytics.a

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := firebase/libapp.a

And added the following to fix the missing header issue:

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/CustomEngine/AnalyticsEngine